# How can I make twitter style's transparent square fluid that's going across vertically?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help me to implement transparent square fluid with bootstrap?(https://twitter.com/ladygaga)

also I'd like to know how to implement rounded square in that transparent square.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you first try inspecting that element using Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools. The answer is right there in the 'Styles' section shown to the right in these tools.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Is it a transparent background? Take a look at this fiddle - http://tinkerbin.com/wO6Xwmks

Comment: If you go to Lady Gaga's twitter page, can't you see half white transparent square going across from very top to bottom? That's what I want for my website:)

Comment: also rounded square in that transparent square:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems they're just using a semitransparent background image on that div to get the glassy texture. The image or background-color(such as `RGBA(0,0,0,0.2)`) would need to have it's alpha channel set to something other than 100%. Their CSS looks like this.

```
.wrapper, .wrapper-narrow, .wrapper-permalink {
    position: relative;
    width: 837px;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 54px 14px 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(../img/wash-white-30.png);
}
```

Assuming you were going to use a similar approach. With a 'wrapper' class providing the transparent background, and a 'whitebg' class providing the solid white background:

```
<div class="container-fluid wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span2 well whitebg">
      content..
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with this CSS to give you what you need for your class:

```
.whitebg {
  background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is what I wanted for my page!! this transparent square is not reaching very edge of the bottom. Where should I change?? probably min-height? or place to put wrapper class? If you put it in container, it's always placed a little bit above than bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The transparent DIV (not square :)) is implemented with a PNG image that has an alpha channel, as follows:

```
.wrapper, .wrapper-narrow, .wrapper-permalink {
    background: url("../img/wash-white-30.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 54px 14px 15px;
    position: relative;
    width: 837px;
}
```

As far as rounded corners are concerned, on that page, they are implemented as follows:

```
.module, .promptbird {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

For your requirements in bootstap, merely using the css opacity property for your div, and the border radius property for your inner divs will do the trick.

```
.transparentDiv { /*make any SQUARE transparent!*/
    background: #fff; /*white*/
    opacity: 0.5 /*will not work in older IE versions, add filter for it!*/
    margin: 0 auto; /* optionally, center it! */
}

.roundedDiv {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; /* 3px looks way cool! */
}
```

usage:

```
<div class="transparentDiv">I see through you baby!</div>
<div class="roundedDiv ">Love makes the world go round!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a transparent color for your `background-color` using an rgba color value. That's how you get the transparency.

For the rounded corners, make it easy by using `border-radius`.

Here's a fiddle containing all the stuff you want - http://tinkerbin.com/j5A3fKHl